# Amazon AWS SNS: How to segment within a topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

Is it possible to segment or send to a sub section of a topic (using SMS)?  We have an application where we are sending "alerts" (not marketing messages) where we may have 10K names on a topic but only want to send to 1-2K.  The messages are time sensitive and we won't know in advance that we'll need to send them.  My original plan was to subscribe them to the topic and point of purchase and then send to just the portion that need it but I can't figure out how that might happen even using message attributes (again for SMS).  I'm using SDK version 3.17 with the API version '2010-03-31'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Individually-addressable endpoints are only usable for Mobile Push.  All of the other transports available through SNS are topic-centric only -- all topic subscribers receive all messages for HTTPS, Email, SQS, and SMS.

The answer is actually found in the "mobile push" section of the FAQ, presumably because those other transports were already established with this limitation when SNS introduced mobile push, which has a feature not available for other transports.

> **Q: Does SNS support direct addressing for SMS or Email?**
>
> No. At this time, direct addressing is only supported for mobile push endpoints (APNS, GCM, ADM, WNS, MPNS, Baidu)
>
> http://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/#mobile-push-notifications

Comment: Thanks that's what I thought but couldn't for the life of me find it anywhere officially.